# algorithm to find a path to move ahead not backward

Tags: algorithm

I have faced interview question,but not able to answer.Can somebody guide me?
Question was--

There is a tunnel which has left and right turns but no T turn like there is no such case that both left and right turn is together.Now I have given three methods

1. `void GoStraight() //To move staright`
2. `void TurnLeft(); //to move left once`
3. `bool IsWall(); //return true if there is wall`

Now to write a program to move ahead without going any backward step.

i have tried but doesnt know how to move right.

```
do
    {
      GoStraight();
    }while(!IsWall())
```

**Updated:**

I got the complete solution,it is like

```
do{
gostraight(); 
if(isWall())
{goLeft();Continue;
}
}while(true);
```

Comment: Did you try _anything_ so far? We don't write program for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
while (IsWall())
    TurnLeft()
GoStraight()
```

Comment: This is the right-hand-rule for solving mazes!! (left-hand in your case)

Comment: Is it just me or wouldn't you go back where you came from if there is a right turn?

Comment: @MAV yep, but you know, ask a stupid question... (don't say that to the interviewer's face!)

Comment: When we are moving straight,we found the wall then we will move left and again we'll check whether there is a wall or not.If there is wall we'll move left else go straight.So,if we are taking two left moves successively,that means we have moved backward from the current position.Isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

```
while(not done)
    while(not IsWall())
        GoStraight()
    TurnLeft()
    if (not IsWall())
        continue
    TurnLeft()
    TurnLeft() // now facing right relative to how we arrived
```

use cases:

```
 *****   * ***
>    *   *   *
 *** *   *** *
 *   *  >    *
 * ***   *****

 R R L   L L R
```